# SQL Server 2005 Data Types - Struggling to get views working with current data types

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqldatatypes

I am in the middle of creating a new database for mobile phones. It includes a lot of information regarding mobile phones, sim cards etc. I am struggling to get the information in the tables converted into a view. I have done a few tests but always receive an error on certain columns. For example, one of the fields is the sim card number which you'll all know is a long number. I have tried having this number as bigint, varchar and nvarchar but always receive an error saying "the conversion of the varchar value 'value' has overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded".

I have a decent level of knowledge when it comes to databases but for some reason I just can't seem to find the right data type for these fields. If someone who has a lot more experience in this could help me out, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT dbo.Sims.Number, 
  dbo.Sims.ACCOLC, 
  dbo.Users.Title, 
  dbo.Users.Name, 
  dbo.Users.Section, 
  dbo.Users.Directorate, 
  dbo.UserHistory.StartDate, 
  dbo.UserHistory.EndDate, 
  dbo.Users.Codes
FROM dbo.UserHistory 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users 
  ON dbo.UserHistory.[User] = dbo.Users.ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Sims 
  ON dbo.UserHistory.Number = dbo.Sims.Number 
INNER JOIN dbo.Models 
  ON dbo.UserHistory.Model = dbo.Models.ID
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast the datatypes from whatever they are in the base tables at all?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Don't understand what you mean by cast the datatypes, sorry!

Comment: Show some code. A view is just a `SELECT` statement. You say "I have tried having this number as bigint, varchar and nvarchar" what do you mean by that if you weren't casting to those datatypes?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I understand that it's just a SELECT statement. Please look at my original question to see the view code I am getting the error with.

Comment: I'd suspect that you've been changing the definition in one table, but that `UserHistory.Number` or `Sims.Number` is still defined as `int`.

Comment: Ahh ok @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have just looked at that and made sure they're the same type and now I don't get any errors but I also don't get any data which is weird. As there is data in all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that I might suggest is to check if you in fact want an `INNER JOIN` between each table. That requires matching rows in all tables, if you do not have the matching row then you won't get a result.

You might want to try changing the `JOIN` type to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.Number, 
  s.ACCOLC, 
  u.Title, 
  u.Name, 
  u.Section, 
  u.Directorate, 
  uh.StartDate, 
  uh.EndDate, 
  uh.Codes
FROM dbo.Users u
LEFT JOIN dbo.UserHistory uh
  ON u.ID = uh.[User] 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Sims s
  ON uh.Number = s.Number 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Models m
  ON uh.Model = m.ID
```

This version will return all `users` even it there are not matching rows in the other tables.